# How to Insert info to the database

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

Sorry for the long post. I got the index.html to work with the quiz1.php, but I can't get the questions and checkbox to work right meaning be inserted to the database with the other info from the index.html. It should insert the info from index.html and the info from quiz1.php. Need help getting this to work.

This is what I have done so far.

Form (index.html) First page (Gets the person info)

```
<form action="quiz1.php" method="post">
    Full Name: <input type="text" name="full_name" />
    Quiz Name: <input type="text" name="quiz_name" />
    Class Name: <input type="text" name="class_name" />
    Date: <input type="text" name="quiz_taken" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="flashit">
</form>
```

Quiz (quiz1.php) Second page (Puts the info from the index.html on the top)

```
<?php
// info from index.html
$_SESSION['full_name']  = $_POST['full_name'];
$_SESSION['quiz_name']  = $_POST['quiz_name'];
$_SESSION['class_name'] = $_POST['class_name'];
$_SESSION['quiz_taken'] = $_POST['quiz_taken'];

echo $_SESSION['full_name'];
echo "<br />";
echo $_SESSION['quiz_name'];
echo "<br />";
echo $_SESSION['class_name'];
echo "<br />";
echo $_SESSION['quiz_taken'];
echo "<br />";
echo "<br />";

?>

// quiz info

<?php

$db_host = "localhost"; 
// Place the username for the MySQL database here 
$db_username = "root";  
// Place the password for the MySQL database here 
$db_pass = "";  
// Place the name for the MySQL database here 
$db_name = "test"; 

// Run the actual connection here  
mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die ("could not connect to mysql");
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die ("no database");

//retreive questions from database and put into question box
$query2 = "SELECT `id`, `question`, `aee`, `bee`, "
        . "`cee`, `dee`, `quizAnswer` FROM `quiz1question`";

$question2    = mysql_query($query2);
$answerFields = array(
                    'aee'=>'aee', 
                    'bee'=>'bee', 
                    'cee'=>'cee', 
                    'dee'=>'dee'
                );

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($question2))
{

    $id         = $row['id'];
    $question   = $row['question'];

    echo '<form action="insert.php" method="post">';

    // Print Question
    printf('<div id="ContainerQuestion">');
    printf('<span class="Question">%s. %s</span>', $id, $question);

    // Print Answers
    foreach ($answerFields as $field=>$ans)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($field, $row) && $row[$field])
        {
            $checked = ($row["quizAnswer"] == $ans) ? 'checked' : '';
            printf(
                '<p><input type="checkbox" name="%s" %s value="%s">%s</p>', 
                $id, 
                $checked, 
                $ans, 
                $row[$field]
            );
        }
    }
}

 echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit Quiz"></form>';

?>
```

results (insert.php) Third page (Input the info from page one and two to the database)

```
<?php 

$localhost = "localhost";
$username  = "root";
$password  = "";
$database  = "test";
$table     = "quiz_results";

mysql_connect("$localhost","$username","$password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("$database") or die(mysql_error());

// question & answers
$mysql1 = "INSERT INTO $table (question, aee, bee, cee, dee) "
        . "VALUES ('$_POST[question]','$_POST[aee]',"
        . "'$_POST[bee]','$_POST[cee]','$_POST[dee]')";

if(!mysql_query($mysql1)) 
{
    die(mysql_error());
}

// insert Name, quiz name, class name, and quiz taken 
$mysql = "INSERT INTO $table (full_name, quiz_name, class_name, quiz_taken) "
       . "VALUES ('$_POST[full_name]','$_POST[quiz_name]',"
       . "'$_POST[class_name]','$_POST[quiz_taken]')";

if(!mysql_query($mysql))
{
    die(mysql_error());
}

// echo
echo"Thank you!"; // mysql1
echo "<br />";
echo"Your Quiz has been Inserted"; // mysql

mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: You say you "Need help getting this to work" but you don't say what it does.  You have to tell us what you expect to happen, and what actually does happen, and how you know that.

Comment: @Andy Lester sorry your right [link](http://ccsb.comyr.com/help/form.html) When I type the info in the index.html works fine shows on top of the quiz1.php. When I take the quiz and hit submit the info is submit to the database from the insert.php which you'll see this message "Thank you!
Your Quiz has been Inserted ", but the database table result is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your quiz1.php.

Effectively your `</form>` was outside the loop, while `<form...>` was inside the loop. This was not constructing proper HTML and most likely was the reason why this would not work.

Also your third script was expecting the `question` element in the `$_POST` array which was never set or sent. Using a hidden field rectifies that.

```
$answerFields = array(
                    'aee' => 'aee', 
                    'bee' => 'bee', 
                    'cee' => 'cee', 
                    'dee' => 'dee'
                );

echo "<form action='insert.php' method='post'>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($question2))
{

    $id         = $row['id'];
    $question   = $row['question'];


    echo "<input type='hidden' name='question' value='{$question}' />"

    // Print Question
    printf('<div id="ContainerQuestion">');
    printf('<span class="Question">%s. %s</span>', $id, $question);

    // Print Answers
    foreach ($answerFields as $field=>$ans)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($field, $row) && $row[$field])
        {
            $checked = ($row["quizAnswer"] == $ans) ? 'checked' : '';
            printf(
                '<p><input type="checkbox" name="%s" %s value="%s">%s</p>', 
                $id, 
                $checked, 
                $ans, 
                $row[$field]
            );
        }
    }

}

echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit Quiz">';
echo '</form>';
```

Finally **PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE** try to change your code to use `PDO` or `mysqli`. mysql* functions have been deprecated and should not be used. There are plenty of tutorials and resources in this site that will help you with this.

Comment: Also, the code is open to SQL injection.  http://bobby-tables.com/php.html has examples of the right way to do SQL inserts with PHP.

Comment: @Nikolaos Dimopoulos The only thing that goes in the database is this {$question}. Also the code you gave me with the form in the loop make the "submit quiz" button show after every question.

Comment: @AgustinLeyva Have a look at the changed code. I moved the form element outside the loop as well as the submit button. This will make your submit show only once **but** it will print the same elements if your loop is for more than one item. That means that it will print elements `bee`, `cee` etc. for one question and continuing the loop elements with the same names for a second or third question. You can use the above with one question per page or you will need to change the names of the checkboxes to ensure uniqueness of data for the submit.

Comment: @NikolaosDimopoulos How do I code it so it can do what you said "one question per page".

Comment: @AgustinLeyva it will require quite a bit of work and checking which question you are on all the time but it can be done. So you load the quiz and treat each question as a page. You can add a `page` field in your database to cater for that. Then all you do is when your page loads you print the question for that page only (and alter your query to get you that page). You check a passed variable like `quiz1.php?p=1` and in the script `$_GET['p']` and you do away with the loop. Alternatively, you will need to create unique HTML elements per question and answer.

Comment: @Nikolaos Dimopoulos Thanks for the help, but I'm very lost.

Comment: Are we talking about Dynamic Pages

Comment: I will create an example for you tomorrow.

Comment: @NikolaosDimopoulos Thanks for the helping hand. Looking forward to your example